# How to sequentially numbering files rather than overwriting them when moving

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing a code that could move the file from one directory to another, but I have an issue with having a file that have the same name, so I decided to number them as I don't want to overwrite them.

Assume I have file a.txt, I succeed to move to move the file with the same name then call it a_1.txt, but I am wondering what I can do if I have again a.txt?

Moreover, I feel my code is not efficient and it will be appreciated if you help me to enhance it.

My code is:

```
/*
 * Method to move a specific file from directory to another
 */
public static void moveFile(String source, String destination) {

    File file = new File(source);

    String newFilePath = destination + "\\" + file.getName();
    File newFile = new File(newFilePath);

    if (!newFile.exists()) {
        file.renameTo(new File(newFilePath));
    } else {
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
        String extention = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getPath());
        System.out.println(fileName);
        if (isNumeric(fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 1))) {
            int fileNum = Integer.parseInt(fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 1));
            file.renameTo(new File(destination + "\\" + fileName + ++fileNum + "." + extention));
        } else {
            file.renameTo(new File(destination + "\\" + fileName + "_1." + extention));
        }
    }//End else
}
```

From the main, I called it as the following (Note that ManageFiles is the class name that the method exist in):

```
    String source = "L:\\Test1\\Graduate.JPG";
    String destination = "L:\\Test2";
    ManageFiles.moveFile(source, destination);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this logic:

If the file already exists in the destination, you add "(1)" to the file name (before the extension). But then you ask me: what if there's already a file with "(1)"? Then you use (2). If there's already one with (2) too, you use (3), and so on.

You can use a loop to acomplish this:

```
/*
 * Method to move a specific file from directory to another
 */
public static void moveFile(String source, String destination) {
    File file = new File(source);
    String newFilePath = destination + "\\" + file.getName();
    File newFile = new File(newFilePath);
    String fileName;
    String extention; 
    int fileNum;
    int cont;
    if (!newFile.exists()) {
        file.renameTo(new File(newFilePath));
    } else {
        cont = 1;
        while(newFile.exists()) {
            fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
            extention = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getPath());
            System.out.println(fileName);
            newFile = new File(destination + "\\" + fileName + "(" + cont++ + ")" + extention);
        }
        newFile.createNewFile();
    }//End else
}
```

Comment: I do not see recursion here.

Comment: Yes you're right I said recursion but did not use it :) Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, really it was helpful. I only make small editing and it works for me. Appreciated your help.